# Test driven development to check database queries involved methods

Tags: mysql, sql, database, go, tdd

I want to create a database driven application using Golang. I am trying to do it TDD way.
When I try to test methods that make Sql queries, What all are the packages available ?

- I don't want to connect to the default database that I use for development. I can write code to take up another test database while running a test, but is there any go library that already does it.
- Is there any library that does db tests without connecting to database at all ?

What is the standard way to do database test with golang ?

Comment: I think you need to mock your data access layer.

Comment: This is what I did at the end - https://github.com/sumitasok/go-test-db . Please give me your thoughts ob this. I will add a Readme soon.

Comment: There is https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock just for that, which is sql driver and fully simulates a database without a real connection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar question not long ago when refactoring some of my own tests, and there's a couple of ways you can do it:

a) Provide an exported type and an `Open` or `Connect` function that returns it - e.g.

```go
type DB struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

// Using http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/ for this example, but
// it has the same interface as database/sql
func Open(opts *Options) (*DB, error) {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect(opts.Driver, fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s", opts.Host, opts.User, opts.Name, opts.SSL))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &DB{db}, nil
}
```

... and then *each of your* tests, write setup & teardown functions that return an instance of `*DB` that you define your database functions on (as methods - i.e. `func (db *DB) GetUser(user *User) (bool, error)`):

```go
// Setup the test environment.
func setup() (*DB, error) {
    err := withTestDB()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // testOptions is a global in this case, but you could easily
    // create one per-test
    db, err := Open(testOptions)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Loads our test schema
    db.MustLoad()
    return db, nil
}

// Create our test database.
func withTestDB() error {
    db, err := open()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    _, err = db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE DATABASE %s;", testOptions.Name))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note that this is somewhat "integration" testing, but I strongly prefer to test against a "real" database since mocking the interface won't help you catch issues with your queries/query syntax.

b) The alternative, although less extensible on the application side, is to have a global `db *sql.DB` variable that you initialise in `init()` within your tests—since tests have no guaranteed order you'll need to use `init()`—and then run your tests from there. i.e.

```go
var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    // Note the = and *not* the assignment - we don't want to shadow our global
    db, err = sqlx.Connect(...)
    if err != nil {
        ...
    }

    err := db.loadTestSchema
    // etc.
}

func TestGetUser(t *testing.T) {
   user := User{}
   exists, err := db.GetUser(user)
   ...
}
```

You can find some practical examples in [drone.io's GitHub repo](https://github.com/drone/drone/tree/master/pkg/database/testing), and I'd also recommend [this article on structuring Go applications](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091) (especially the DB stuff).

Comment: This is what I did at the end - https://github.com/sumitasok/go-test-db . Please give me your thoughts ob this. I will add a Readme soon.

Comment: BTW, the explanation you gave way very precise.

Comment: That init func can be replaced with TestMain() I think.

Comment: @alexsmn Good point. TestMain didn't exist when I wrote this originally, but is the preferred way to do test setup now.

Comment: I'm probably missing something simple here, but any input on how I can run migrations with option (a)? I have all the migrations defined in `.sql` files in a `db` directory within the project...

Answer (score 1):

I use a global variable to store the data source (or connection string) of current database and set to different value in test function. Since there is only one database I need to operate so I choose the easiest way.